# Table - size first column based on largest cell

Tags: html, css

Here is the effect I am trying to achieve:

[image] [image]

Here is what I currently have:

[image]

HTML:

```
<ul class="route-list"><li><span class="line">A</span><div class="route-operator"><div class="route">Southampton</div><div class="operator">Velvet</div></div></li></ul>
```

CSS: `Check JSFiddle`

I want to achieve an effect that will choose the right size of the first column for me but without using a fixed size.

You will see that is what my current attempt does. The issue with this is it takes up a lot of space that could be used more efficiently. The solution needs to have a maximum width like my current fixed width solution, I don't want it to show anything larger than 3 characters.

#### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tJ9Dd/)

Thanks

Comment: If i understand right, you want 'A' letter to be close to 'Eastleigh'?

Comment: @Alek Correct, but it should also fit nicely up to about a max size of 30%

Comment: You don't want `text-align:right` `.route-list li .line` instead of `center`?

Comment: @Alek Would still defeat the purpose, I'm trying to preserve room

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `display: table;` on the `li`, but `display: table-row;` does what you need (if I'm reading your problem correctly).

`table-row` makes an element behave like a `<tr>`.

See http://jsfiddle.net/tJ9Dd/1/

Comment: Ahhhhhhhhh perfect thanks Stephen! Do you know if there's a way I can set a max-width on the line class? Ideally I want it to stop expanding after around 3 letters/20-30%, should I use JavaScript to do this instead or is it possible with CSS?